# Visual Basic 6.0 form designer - cannot drag to move objects

Tags: user-interface, drag-and-drop, vb6, form-designer

I am a newbie for Visual Basic 6 project.  I downloaded some tutorials for testing; however, I am not able to drag, move, or edit the UI form designer objects in those projects.

Does anybody know there is an object lock function in VB6?
If there is, how can I unlock it?

Answer (score 3):

Are you saying that you're in the VB6 forms designer, and you cannot move any of the controls on the form?

If that's the case, I seem to remember that there's a "locked" property for the form - the setting for it should be in the properties window.

Hope that helps...

Comment: +1. It's not shown in the properties window. There is a "lock controls" button on the "form editor" toolbar, and a "lock controls" option on the "Format" menu. You can see the setting in the .FRM file in Notepad `LockControls = -1` as mentioned in Guarita's answer.

Answer (score 3):

I read this in a post, it was the following google search link after this one for 'vb6 unlock drag move'. It worked for me.

> This may not be the problem but it's something that you can check:
>   There's a hidden setting (Microsoft even hides settings from programmers!) that will cause controls to be unmoveable. Open the .FRM file in Notepad. If it contains a line: LockControls = -1 then remove that line.

Original poster was named 'Mayayana' at: http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic/answers/14881-cant-move-controls-form

Comment: That's the same property mentioned in Richard's answer.

Comment: Well noticed. I'd delete this answer and add the information above in the comments of the previous answer but I'm not finding any option to add a comment to Richard Ev's answer. - is it closed or anything like that?

Comment: I've added the comment. Maybe you need to get a bit more rep (50+ ?) before you can comment freely. +1 to you BTW, that'll help with the rep :)

Comment: I guess it was just that (50+ rep). I just commented on another question now and realized that! I'll leave the answer here as I'd be voting for deleting instead of actually deleting it. (that's what the help label says about the 'delete' link). Oh, thanks for the +1 by the way!