# vb6 showing type mismatch in function

Tags: vb6

This is my code to lock controls in VB6

```
Private Function lockControls()
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox _
        Or TypeOf ctrl Is ComboBox _
        Or TypeOf ctrl Is NumBox _
        Or TypeOf ctrl Is OptionButton _
        Or TypeOf ctrl Is DTPicker Then
            ctrl.Enabled = True
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

But when I try to run the program it is showing type mismatch and is not giving any hint.
Can anyone say what is wrong in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB6 has a [hidden property `LockControls`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13163712/11683) that controls locking controls on the form. Your function name, `lockControls`, conflicts with it.

Rename the function.

Answer (score 0):

If you're receiving the error:

> error DATA TYPE MISMATCH in FUNCTION OBJECT "FUNCTION1"

Go to your mdb file and change the datatype of your fields.

Comment: go to datasheet then select data type and choose number.